# Function in React (-Native) functional component does not see changed state value after being invoked

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using expo to playback an audio recording, however the callback method doesn't not see the new assigned value.

A button calls this method:

```
1  // handles play/pause
2  const playAudio = async (audioRecording, audioRecordingTime, messageId) 3 => {
4      console.log('audioRecordingInState', audioRecordingInState);
5
6      try {
7        const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();
8        await soundObject.loadAsync({ uri: audioRecording });
9
10       soundObject.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(e => handlePlayBack(e));
11
12       const newStateSoundObject = {
13         soundObject,
14         messageId,
15         isPlaying: true
16       };
17
18       setAudioRecordingInState(newStateSoundObject);
19
20       await soundObject.playAsync();
21     } catch (err) {
22       console.log(err);
23     }
24 }
```

And a `handlePlayback` is:

```
25  const handlePlayBack = async ({ didJustFinish }) => {
26    console.log("recording", audioRecordingInState);
27    if (didJustFinish) {
28      try {
29        setAudioRecordingInState(null);
30      } catch (err) {
31       console.log("err caught stopping", err);
32     }
33   }
34 };
```

Whenever the button is clicked, the audio plays and I hear it, however the line 26 keeps printing null, when it should be printing `newStateSoundObject`. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: I've tested with a useEffect with `audioRecordingInState` as a dependency, and the state does indeed change, however clicking the button to play the audio, and then clicking it again to pause, prints null (line 4). This is in addition to the printed null on line 26.

Comment: You can also try logging it inside your return, so you can see all the changes that are happening to your state.

Comment: I know that the state is changing, I've tested that in a useEffect with `audioRecordingInState` as the dependency. But `handlePlayback` doesn't seem to see the change. Is it because I'm doing `soundObject.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(e => handlePlayBack(e));` before `audioRecordingInState` is set to an object?

Comment: I would either 1) do a useEffect which depends on state and then triggers the function you want (that will involve a bit of refactoring of the code) or 2) using a ref, because ref always keeps itself up to date and you should have the correct value of the state when you look at it again.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean I should use `useRef` intead of `const [audioRecordingInState, setAudioRecordingInState] = useState(null);`?